# Converting ASP to ASP.NET - Easy or hard?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp-classic

I have a client who's site is done in ASP... they want to add a lot of extra functionality to the site but I don't think it's worth it to keep developing in Classic ASP & they should move to either .NET or PHP.

I don't know much about .NET so was wondering if ASP code can be converted to .NET code at all & if so how much effort is involved in it?

**Edit:** What's this all about? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973813.aspx

Comment: I think you are better off if you write the site completely new. If you don't wanna do that I recommend to migrate part by part of the old website to new asp.net technology which is 90% different to old asp.

Comment: I think your first problem should be the "I don't know much about .NET".

Comment: @xanatos: Fair point lol.... If I was going to rebuild the site I would probably do it in PHP. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET was a big departure from ASP.  However, I disagree with what everyone else seems to be saying.

In 2002 I converted a large ASP website to ASP.NET.  If you're going from VBScript to VB.NET, then in fact there is a lot of legacy functionality that's carried over.  You don't even have to adopt the codebehind architecture common to ASP.NET web forms if you don't want to.  You can even use the classic `<!--#include-->` files just as you did with ASP.

I mean, there's a lot that will break when migrating to ASP.NET.  Data access, for example, is completely different. But there's also a lot that can be carried over.

So you've got two options:

1. Dive in and see what breaks with minimal changes.  This may not sound wise, but it's what I did.  And with Visual Studio helping you along with compile-time errors, you should be able to finish the project a lot faster this way.
2. Rewrite from scratch doing things the new ASP.NET way.  This will allow you to bill for more time, and make your application a little more future-proof.

In all honesty I'd prefer option #2 today.  But I thought you should know that conversion is possible (and with less work overall).

Answer (score 3):

> I don't know much about .NET so was
>   wondering if ASP code can be converted
>   to .NET code at all & if so how much
>   effort is involved in it?

There is pretty much nothing in common between the two.  You are most likely looking at a full rewrite to do the upgrade.  Really keeping it in Classic ASP is going to start hampering their ability to expand the site.  Visual Basic 6 (non-.Net) isn't around anymore (assuming the core logic is written in compiled VB dlls) and won't run in an x64 IIS instance.

Comment: Is it possible to share state, login sessions and what not between an ASP classic and ASP.NET session? Is it reasonable to migrate a site one step at a time and manage to keep it together?

Comment: There are ways of sharing session between two, but I believe it involves posting information to the asp.net and classic asp site manually.  It's been a while since I've had to do anything like that, so my memory maybe a little fuzzy, but I know there are ways to get it to work.

Comment: A recent client of mine had a ASP/ASP.NET solution running and it was working great. They still had the login page in ASP and other stuff in ASP.NET so session state is shareable, that's for sure.

Comment: of course it is possible to run a vb6 dll on an x64 iis instance

Answer (score 2):

There is no way you successfully convert a ASP site into a ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC website.

However, you can reuse HTML and images and such, even though it might be outdated.

Comment: I guess that is a how to, but if you keep the structure and logic from a ASP website and actually make it run, you will end up with a pretty messy code base. 
You are better off rewriting the whole thing. And nowadays you can even find pretty complete websites that you can start building from, such as Orchard CMS for instance.

Answer (score 0):

They're nothing alike. You'd have to manually recode it in the new language.

This probably sounds hard to do, but it's worth learning a *modern* server-side language.

Whether it's worth it in this specific instance depends on how complicated the site in question is.

Answer (score 0):

Check **[this Microsoft's presentation](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/migrating-from-classic-asp-to-aspnet)** on how to migrate an ASP application to ASP.NET 2.0.

To summarize, that's not going to be straightforward, even though they present some "if you are short on time" migration tactics.